# Memory use increases when using NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, memory, nsdata

I'm using an NSOperation to download images. The images are used in a collection view. Using Instruments I could not find the reason for the increasing memory use (I still find it difficult the understand the Allocations part in Instruments). I started commenting out parts of my code to see where the problem occurs.

The NSOperation is defined as follows:

```
class ImageDownloader: NSOperation {
    var url: String
    var imageData: NSData?

    init(url: String) {
        self.url = url
    }

    override func main() {
        if self.cancelled {
            return
        }

        if let imageUrl = NSURL(string: url) {
             // retrieve data from web
             imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl)
        }

        imageData = nil    // This line is added so the rest of the code is not handling the result. This way I am able to pinpoint the source of the increasing memory
        return
    }
}
```

The function set imageData back to nil, before returning. This way I make sure the rest of the code is not handling the result and therefore does not increase the memory. The result is an empty collection view.

If I run the code like stated in the code above I can see the memory increasing while I am scrolling the collection view. But there is no increasing memory when I comment out the line

```
//      imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl)
```

I hope someone can explain why the memory used by NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl) is not completely released after the operation is finished?
What can I change to avoid the increase of memory while scrolling?

Comment: i think to download image you should use SDWebImage (third party libarary ) they manage very good all things  [https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would like to understand why the memory is increasing with my own code.

Comment: iOS maintains in-memory caches in various places. `NSData(contentsOfURL:)` must internally use `NSURLSession` (or some equivalent), which uses an in-memory (and on-disk) cache. How big is the memory increase you see?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem: I have a retain cycle with the NSOperation. The completion block references 'self'. Therefore all operations that are created are not released. The memory increase is due to the imageData variable in the operation.

I do not know yet how to solve this retain cycle. I will post another question for this problem: [Swift: Retain cycle with NSOperation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528333/swift-retain-cycle-with-nsoperation)